# Count sequentially matching values in column python

Tags: python, count, series, sequential

I have a column in a dataframe as such:

x

0
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0

What I would like to do is create a new column that sums up the groups of 1s that follow one another, only when there are more than 3 adjacent 1s.So the output I want is

> ```
> x y
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 1 4
> 1 4
> 1 4
> 1 4
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 1 0
> 1 0
> 1 0
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 1 8 
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 1 8
> 0 0
> 0 0
> 0 0
> ```

So in the first set of 1s, there are four of them, so I show a count of 4 in column y.
In the second set of 1s, there are three of them, but I do not show a count in column y.
In the third set of 1s, there are eight of them, so I should a count of 8 in column y.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#create Series for distinguish groups
a = df['x'].ne(df['x'].shift()).cumsum()
#remove 0 rows
df1 = df[df['x'] != 0]

#get counts, add 0 for zero rows and last replace values < 4
df['y'] = (df1.groupby(a)['x']
              .transform('size')
              .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
              .mask(lambda x: x < 4, 0))
```

---

Another faster solution:

```
#create groups
a = df['x'].ne(df['x'].shift()).cumsum()
#remove rows of groups where 0 and count output
b = a[df['x'] != 0].value_counts()
#get only values by condition
d = b[b >= 4]
#map to original, replace NaNs to 0 and last cast to int
df['y'] = a.map(d).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)

    x  y
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   0  0
3   1  4
4   1  4
5   1  4
6   1  4
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   1  0
10  1  0
11  1  0
12  0  0
13  0  0
14  0  0
15  0  0
16  1  8
17  1  8
18  1  8
19  1  8
20  1  8
21  1  8
22  1  8
23  1  8
24  0  0
25  0  0
26  0  0
```